# I need to append some li tag structure using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to append li and ul tag using jquery on  click event on specific tag.

i am using following method for append :

```
 $(".education_elements").append(<put below Html code>);
```

Here is my html which i am need to append.

```
 <li class="education_element_1">                                        
     <ul>
           <li>
            <div class="right-side">
                <div class="iwill">
                    <input type="text" size="60" class="do_input text_do_input"  name="education_jobtitle" value="" id="education_jobtitle" placeholder="Please type your school or collage name here" /> <br/><span class="text_right">*<?php _e('Minimum 30 & Maximum 60 Character','PricerrTheme'); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <h2>Course<span class="mark tooltip" title="Please type the title of your advert in this box.">?</span></h2>
         <div class="right-side">
            <div class="iwill">
                <input type="text" size="40" class="do_input text_do_input"  name="education_cource" value="" id="education_cource" placeholder="Please type your course title here"/></span>
             </div>
         </div>
         </li>
        <li>
            <h2>From<span class="mark tooltip" title="Please type the title of your advert in this box.">?</span></h2>
             <div class="right-side">
                <div class="iwill">
                    <input type="text" size="40" class="do_input text_do_input"  name="education_from" value="" id="education_from" placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY"/></span>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </li>                     
        <li>
            <h2>To<span class="mark tooltip" title="Please type the title of your advert in this box.">?</span></h2>
             <div class="right-side">
                <div class="iwill">
                    <input type="text" size="40" class="do_input text_do_input"  name="education_to" value="" id="education_to" placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY"/></span>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2><?php echo __('Status', 'PricerrTheme'); ?><span class="mark tooltip" title="Will you provide your customers support after the session; most people like to follow up with their mentors and coaches. If you'd like to provide support through email message please select its duration.">?</span></h2>
            <div class="right-side">
                <select class="do_input select_do_input" name="education_status" id="education_status">
                    <option value="">Please Select Your Course Status</option>
                    <option value="No Support">Passed (completed)</option>
                    <option value="One Week">Failed (re-doing)</option>
                    <option value="Two Weeks">Failed (quited)</option>
                    <option value="Three Weeks">Currently Doing (outgoing)      </option>
                </select>   
            </div>                                          
        </li>  
    </ul>                                   
</li>
```

if any one know any other method for this so please tell me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do the (very) basic jQuery operation:

```
$('.education_elements').append($('li.education_element_1').html());
```

?

Comment: when i am using this code it give me following error :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: That doesn't happen to me, all works fine. Maybe the error comes from something else?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery append accepts html string or html element.

So whatever you want to append if it's present in dom then just write:-

```
$(".education_elements").append($('li.education_element_1'));
```

And if it's not in dom you can write

```
 $(".education_elements").append('<li class="education_element_1">..<li>');
```

Another thing you can do, just keep your whole html within script tag in the body like

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
     <li class="education_element_1">..<li>
</script>
```

And then append the html using:-

```
$(".education_elements").append($('#template').html());
```

Comment: But i need to append dynamically on <a> tag click event more than 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: Are you appending same html every time after each click or every time you're appending different html?

Answer (score 0):

Put the HTML code in a variable and append that variable with $('parent').html(variable)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use:

```
$('.education_elements').append($('li.education_element_1')[0].outerHtml);
```

Should work like a charm, only if the element is inside your DOM. But, I strongly recommend moving that entire html to a separate php file, and load it with jquery load, that way you will end up having a more cleaner html, something rought like this:

Your `<li class="education_element_1">` would live in a file, lets say `dynamicLi.php`, and then you just simply do:

```
$(".education_elements").load("dynamicLi.php");
```

This is just a recommendation, but I believe it's a good approach in order to keep things tidy and well organized.